# Find the equation of a line that is tangent to both parabolas simultaneously

Tags: calculus, derivatives, tangent-line, slope

Consider the parabolas $y=x^2$ and $y=x^2-2x+2$. How to find the equation of a line that is tangent to both of them at the same time? Please, walk me through the most intuitive solution.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

- Let $(a, a^2)$ and $(b, b^2 - 2b + 2)$ be the two points of tangency on the common tangent line.
- Independently compute the equation of both tangent lines.

> You should get:
> $$
> \begin{cases}
> y - a^2 = 2a(x - a) \\
> y - (b^2 - 2b + 2) = (2b - 2)(x - b) \\
> \end{cases}
> \iff
> \begin{cases}
> y = (2a)x - a^2 \\
> y = (2b - 2)x - b^2 + 2 \\
> \end{cases}
> $$

- Compare coefficients to obtain a system of two equations and two unknowns.

> You should get:
> $$
> \begin{align*}
> 2a &= 2b - 2 \\
> -a^2 &= -b^2 + 2 \\
> \end{align*}
> $$

- Solve the system and plug the values back in to obtain the equation of the tangent line.

Comment: I'm stuck on the second step. This is all I got so far:

$a$ = x coordinate for the $x^2$ curve. 
$b$ = x coordinate for the $x^2-2x+2$ curve.

Slope of the first tangent line = $2a$. So $y = 2ax+B$ is the equation for the first tangent line? 

Slope of the second tangent line = $2b-2$. So $y=(2b-2)x+B$ is the equation for the second tangent line? 

Where do I go now?

Comment: I've edited in steps two and three.

Answer (score 2):

Let the tangent line be $y = mx + b$. We know that both $mx +b = x^2$ and $mx+b = x^2-2x+2$ have one single solution, which implies that the discriminants of those quadratic equations are zero:
$$
m^2+4b =0, \quad (m+2)^2-4(2-b)=0
$$

This leads to $m=1$ and $b = -\frac 14$.